# How to set initial view controller for swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I normally use storyboard to set a view controller as initial view controller by clicking in the attribute inspector.

How can I set initial view controller in swift UI?

System info: Swift 5, Xcode 11.3.1.

Comment: You don’t really use view controllers in SwiftUI. No storyboards either. It’s all View :) The answer below shows how to set a different View as the initial view. If you want to switch content, for example logged in / not logged in, you can you a RootView for example with an if statement in its body and conditionally load a different child view.

Comment: I see, i guess in that case there can't be a way to use both swiftui and viewcontroller in the same project or is there?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. Google swiftui & viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SceneDelegate.swift

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

change the line `let contentView = ContentView()...` to `YourInitialView()...`

The result should look like this

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // change this line to your initial view controller class name
    let contentView = YourInitalView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no idea how long it took me to find this

Comment: hey
from where "context" came? -Cannot find 'context' in scope

Comment: it comes from scenedelegate. I think if you use swiftui2.0 or higher you can't use this anymore

Comment: Once the `contentView` is dismissed, how do you go back to initial view controller? Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648571/insert-optional-view-controllers-before-rootviewcontroller-storyboard) question for details.

Answer (score -3):

You can not use UIViewController with SwiftUI, In SwiftUI Views are Struct.

Step to change Initial View in SwiftUI

1. Open SceneDelegate (Not AppDelegate)
2. Upate scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) func like below

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = SignInInputView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

where SignInInputView is Stuct like below

```
struct SignInInputView: View {
    @State private var userNameString: String = ""
    @State private var passwordString: String = ""
    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                TextField("Enter UserName/Password", text: $userNameString, onEditingChanged: { (value) in
                    print(value)
                }, onCommit: {
                    print(self.userNameString)
                }).frame(height: 60)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                    .background(Color.red)

                TextField("Enter Password", text: $passwordString, onEditingChanged: { (value) in
                    print(value)
                }, onCommit: {
                    print(self.passwordString)
                }).frame(height: 60)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
        }
    }
}
```