# Insert optional view controller(s) before rootViewController storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

I have a root view controller (or initial view controller) designated in storyboard in Xcode. It is neither navigation or tab bar controller, just a custom `UIViewController`. My problem is I optionally would want to insert another introductory view(s) or view controller(s) before this initial view controller. The view/view controller(s) could be product tours, paywall, or introductory offers. The initial view controller takes around 1 second to load so it is best to defer its loading until the introductory view controller is shown and dismissed by the user. And once the introductory view is dismissed, I want to load my initial view controller. What is the correct method to achieve the same?

Comment: You need to choose the root view controller with code in your scene delegate.  You can't do it with a Storyboard alone

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, lets presume that is done in scene delegate. How do I transfer control back to initial view controller in Storyboard once intro views are dismissed?

Comment: You can instantiate your initial view controller (introductory) from the storyboard and then use segues from it or you can use code to replace the root view controller of your scene.